# Changing the state of an entity in a multi threaded environment using Stored Procedures

Tags: .net, sql-server, thread-safety, t-sql, lock-free

According to my current design various processes and threads(written in .net core or framework) will call this stored procedure to change the status of various entities in a multi threaded environment:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StatusChangedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL
) 
GO

insert into table1(Status, StatusChangedOn) values (0, GETDATE())

GO
Create or ALTER  proc usp_ChangeStatus
    @entityId as int
    ,@currentStatus int
    ,@nextStatus int
as
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @updatedIDs TABLE
    (
        Id INT NOT NULL
    )

  update table1
  set status = @nextStatus , StatusChangedOn = GETDATE()
  OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @updatedIds
  where id = @entityId and Status = @currentStatus

  select Id from @updatedIDs
END;
GO

exec usp_ChangeStatus 1 , 0 , 10
exec usp_ChangeStatus 1 , 0 , 10
```

Do you think a transaction also should be explicitly began or this is enough for managing racing conditions ?

And also the result of running this SP and observing its output should be enough to omit the use of "**lock**" and its relevant methods right ?

Comment: All of the work in your SP is done in the single `update` statement and, if not part of an explicit transaction, will execute in an implicit transaction. There remains the larger question of whether access to your `entities` needs to be synchronized to avoid race conditions or other issues. Aside: It's a best practice to return an explicit column list rather than `select * ...`. In this case `@UpdatedIds` only has one column and seems like the schema is unlikely to change, but it's a good habit to avoid `*`.

Comment: @HABO I updated the query regarding the * issue.  
Also I have assumed that whoever of the clients who sees the intended entity Id in their SP's output is the winner of the racing condition and non of the other clients can get the same result as the winner.  
As a result the intended entity completely  belongs to the winner and it can apply its changes safely to that entity. I was hopping that someone can see a flaw in this plan and show me a scenario in which my assumption is failing.